# Distribution of distance to nearest (farthest) neighbour in normal data cloud

Tags: distributions, spatial, distance, point-process

Here is an example of standard normal datasets (spherical, i.e. identity covariance matrices) in 1, 2, 3, 5, 10 dimensions, `n=100` points. The picture shows observed distributions of the euclidean distance from every data point to its nearest neighbour point:

[image]

And, likewise, from every data point to its farthest neighbour point:

[image]

What theoretical distributions does that follow? **What is** the distance distribution to the **nearest neighbour**? To the **farthest neighbour**? In normal data of varying dimensionality. Experts on distributions and point process in space, please, supply me with formulas and good links.

Comment: I think in all cases the distributions follow the max and min order statistics of a scaled chi random variable. As in the nearest neighbour will follow the min and the futthest the max, with the number of dimensions a function of the degrees of freedom. I will right up a more detailed proof when I get time.